# Seaborn FacetGrid (scatterplot) skips NaN values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, nan, facet-grid

While plotting FacetGrid with seaborn - it skips Nan values and plots just in ongoing order.

primary df:

```
          Country Name       1995       1998       2002       2006       2010        2014       2018  
0              Armenia   6.700000   9.400000        NaN        NaN  19.007999   17.498501  18.965900  
1           Azerbaijan   0.800000   1.130000  10.040000   6.620000   5.630000    4.910000   4.900000
```

Then I do melt and plot, so code is below:

```
df_unemployment = pd.melt(df_unemployment, id_vars='Country Name')
df_unemployment.rename(columns = {'variable': 'Year', 'value': '%'}, inplace=True)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_unemployment, col='Country Name', hue='Country Name', sharey=True,col_wrap=6)
g = g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, 'Year','%')
```

Armenia data:

[image]

as result it skips 2002 and 2006 Nan values for Armenia:

[image]

How can I handle it ? I donot want to fill NaN`s with averages or '0'.

Comment: Are you asking how to leave 2002 and 2006 "empty" in the left plot or are you asking what value to replace the NaN with conceptually? The latter depends on your data and what a NaN means in this context.

Comment: I want to keep 2002 and 2006 "empty".

Comment: This is the default behavior if the entries themselves are `np.NaN` (if it isn't for some reason, try updating the library).

Comment: I made graph with point-plot instead of scatter-plot. It somehow solved the issue.